# using sysfs show() and store() functions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I have 2 questions regarding using these functions. I don't completely understand the documentation written [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt):

> sysfs allocates a buffer of size (PAGE_SIZE) and passes it to the
>   method. Sysfs will call the method exactly once for each read or
>   write. This forces the following behavior on the method
>   implementations:
>
> - On read(2), the show() method should fill the entire buffer. 
>     Recall that an attribute should only be exporting one value, or an
>     array of similar values, so this shouldn't be that expensive.
>
>   This allows userspace to do partial reads and forward seeks
>     arbitrarily over the entire file at will. If userspace seeks back to
>     zero or does a pread(2) with an offset of '0' the show() method will
>     be called again, rearmed, to fill the buffer.
> - On write(2), sysfs expects the entire buffer to be passed during the
>     first write. Sysfs then passes the entire buffer to the store() method.
>     A terminating null is added after the data on stores. This makes
>     functions like sysfs_streq() safe to use.
>
>   When writing sysfs files, userspace processes should first read the
>     entire file, modify the values it wishes to change, then write the
>     entire buffer back.

First, when I read/write to the sysfs attribute file with `read/write`, am I guaranteed that the buffer I read to / the buffer in the `store` function will have all of the bytes I wanted to read in that function, and not call it in several chunks?

Also, how is the null character added? That is, suppose I wrote n bytes, will the amount of written bytes be n in the function parameter, and the null char will be placed at n+1?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to first questions yes - partial writes are not supported and the buffer is always filled in one call of show method.

The answer to 2nd question is also yes. See implementation `kernfs_fop_write()` which is used by sysfs - it will allocate up to PAGE_SIZE+1 bytes so that there is enough space to fit \0.

Comment: Actually PAGE_SIZE or 2*PAGE_SIZE (so null terminator in that case takes full page).

Answer (score 0):

It allocates `PAGE_SIZE` and, if `>= PAGE_SIZE` were written, it truncates to `PAGE_SIZE` with a `'\0'` and logs an error. If `> PAGE_SIZE` were written, you probably corrupted kernel memory.

For protection, you should use `sysfs_emit` and `sysfs_emit_at` to write to the buffer. See the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/sysfs.html).